# Does it matter if I create a PHP session before creating a cookie-based session?

Tags: php, session-cookies

I'm a beginner but I can't seem to find the answer.
I'm working on a project with a login system and it will require both PHP sessions and cookies.

As I understand, sessions with user-side cookies or PHP (I know these are basically server side cookies) both have to have their code in the header/before the  tag.

I've learned that coding semantics can be particular so I'm wondering which session code goes first, or do you create them at the same time?

Comment: No it doesn't matter. Just make sure anything that touches your headers is done before you output anything. And remember that if you aren't using session data, you have to assume anything coming in via the cookie is malicious. Sanitize and error check everything.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. And thanks for the wise reminder regarding potentially malicious cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Some more pointers:

1. Cookies are sent with HTTP headers that must be sent before any other output including any html or whitespace.
2. php have session_start() and related functions that gets/sets session stuff for you
3. With a started session, you can use the $_SESSION array to store data between multiple requests. You want to put your user_id etc there.
4. It isn't hard to implement the session stuff yourself. You may want to do it for learning purposes, or if you have a complex system. In this case, make sure you sanitize cookie values and security check everything